# Яндекс api 2.1, как через ymaps.suggest выдавать список только городов и адреса

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Как реализовать выдачу списка только городов и адресов, в базовом виде если ввести Минск, то выдает вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а хотелось бы, чтоб выводил список городов и адресов, для того чтобы можно было дальше проложить маршрут по тому что выбрал пользователь, логично что ненужно прокладывать маршруты с областей или регионов.

Answer (score 1):

Ограничить сами поисковые подсказки не получится, но вы можете проверять полноту введенного адреса и просить дополнить его, если введен только город.

Есть [пример в песочнице Яндекса](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/input_validation?from=SO)

Comment: не совсем то что нужно, постоянно выводить сообщение о том что вы не то ввели, обычно отталкивает клиентов. Но спасибо за идею

Comment: в поисковых подсказках можно только ограничить приоритетную область поиска объектов через boungingBox, но запретить "слишком крупные" объекты не получится.
в общем случае нет ничего страшного и в маршруте до города - за точку назначения будет принят геометрический центр населенного пункта.

Comment: так мне и нужен маршрут по городам и улицам, но когда я начинаю вводит город Минск, он мне еще выводит "Беларусь, минская область, минский район" как отдельное поле, кликнув на нее он возьмет центр минского района, вот по этому хотелось чтоб не выводило так, а искало только совпадения по городам и улицам